# How to give execute button inside text area which already contain query from back-end(java) using angularJS like as finished button in apache zeppelin

Tags: angularjs

How to give execute button inside text area which already contain query from back-end(java) and when we click on that execute button text area has to be refreshed along with modified data using angularJS same as in apache zeppelin.

I am new to angularJS,so could you people help me?

this is my controller code:

```
         $http.get().then(function(resp){
             console.log(resp.data.body.paragraphs);
             $scope.pass = resp.data.body.paragraphs;
             });
```

this is my HTML code:

```
<div ng-repeat="i in pass">
   <textarea id="textarea" rows="10" ng-if="i.text" >{{i.text}} </textarea> 
</div>
```

Comment: To deploy a button on top of other element, you need to use absolute positioning (nothing to do with AngularJS) and give it the proper Z-INDEX value (so that it is shown on top of whatever is within the text area).

Comment: thanks for your suggestion,can you send me any code with example?if possible.

Comment: Unfortunately, no time to write sample code and test it. Just google for css position absolute and z-index can be given a very large number (e.g. 100000).

Comment: thanks,i wrote code like this it is working

Comment: <div class="textarea " contenteditable="true" >
   <a class="button" style="float:right">Finished</a>
 <pre>{{i.text}}</pre>
</div>

Comment: Great! If my comments were of any help, I'd appreciate if you up-vote them (just click at the up-arrow shown at the left of my comment(s) when you move the mouse to the left of the comment). Thanks!

Comment: thanks for your support!